# Toilet Extender Causing Slow Flush Because of Venting Issue

Tags: plumbing, toilet

This toilet flushes very slowly, and after much investigating.  It has been determined that the adapter used to move the toilet further away from the wall causes the water not to vent.

The plumbing company has said that in order to fix it, they need to jackhammer the floor to the main and shift the pipe.

Are there any more straightforward ways of accomplishing this?  They quoted $5k plumbing and $1k floor repair.

[image]

Comment: I'm no plumber, but "the adapter ... causes the water not to vent" sounds like BS to me. The toilet is not supposed to 'vent' through there - the vent is supposed to be a completely separate section of pipe connected to the drain plumbing nearby.

Comment: "The plumbing company has said to fix it." - Have you tried telling them to go pound salt? What authority do they have to make such demands?

Comment: This is one of the better offset flanges on the market and it shouldn't make much difference in the flushing of the toilet. If there's a venting problem, check the vent for clogging.  What's all that wax doing in the bowl of the flange?

Comment: Offset flanges can cause issues but I would say BS on venting, high efficiency low volume toilet is probably more of an issue they just want to change it to a sweep instead of offset the venting probably won’t be changed, 6k sounds way high but prices are off topic.

Comment: When did this problem start? Try pouring a bucket of water in there, about 1.5 gallons. See if it drains slowly or not, if it does then @ed beal identified the issue.

Comment: We had the vents checked.  The toilet in the next bathroom that isn't using the flange is working fine (same vent).  We had a low water toilet on here that continually would clog.  I replaced it with a standard big tank toilet, and it does the same thing.  You can see the slowness in flushing.  When you take the toilet off, the pipe is dry, and we did a camera, and the line is empty.  This plumber was a different company we had to check it because it's been a long time and no one has been able to find the problem.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I have edited that sentence to reflect what I believe the OP meant. I don't think the plumbing company is demanding that this be fixed. Of course, you could have just been pointing out the grammar error in a subtle, sarcastic way that I totally failed to pick up on.

Comment: @EdBeal What do you suggest since I've swapped out the low volume toilet to see if that would fix it?  See my other comments for details.